# Object Vba read items

Tags: vba, excel

I can not read Movie Object, I don't know Why??, I'm trying to return an JSOn API to my sheet in excel, buy I can not read the Movie Object.

```
Sub getData()

Dim Movie As Object
Dim R As Object
Dim scriptControl As Object

Set scriptControl = CreateObject("MSScriptControl.ScriptControl")
scriptControl.Language = "JScript"

With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    .Open "GET", "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/shift/", False
    .send
    Set R = scriptControl.Eval("(" + .responsetext + ")")
    .abort
    With Sheets("API")
        For Each Movie In R
            MsgBox (Movie.Name)
            .Cells(1, 2).Value = Movie.price_btc
            .Cells(1, 3).Value = Movie.price_usd
            .Cells(1, 4).Value = Movie.Rank
        Next Movie
    End With
End With
```

End Sub

I create a Sheet named API to return values but I don't know how retrive value elements in Movie Object

You can check in debug than Movie contain data but when I try to put in cell send an error:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing JSON in Excel VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6627652/parsing-json-in-excel-vba)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that certain properties of javascript objects cannot directly be accessed in VBA if their name matches a VBA keyword (or possible some other "reserved" term). "name" is an example - you will see you cannot write `Movie.name` without the case getting switched to `Movie.Name`

Here's one approach which uses javascript to access the properties, but you might be better off using something like VBAjson (https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON) since it offers a better "multi-purpose" approach.

```
Sub getData()

    Dim Movie As Object
    Dim R As Object
    Dim sc As Object, x

    Set sc = CreateObject("MSScriptControl.ScriptControl")
    sc.Language = "JScript"

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/shift/", False
        .send
        sc.Eval ("var i, o = (" + .responsetext + ")")
        sc.Eval "function l(){return o.length;}"
        sc.Eval "function indx(n){i=n;}"
        sc.Eval "function p(pname){return o[i][pname];}"

        .abort

        With Sheets(1)
            For x = 1 To sc.Eval("l()")
                sc.Eval "indx(" & x - 1 & ")" 'set array index

                'get properties at that index
                .Cells(1, 2).Value = sc.Eval("p('name')")
                .Cells(1, 2).Value = sc.Eval("p('price_btc')")
                .Cells(1, 3).Value = sc.Eval("p('price_usd')")
                .Cells(1, 4).Value = sc.Eval("p('Rank')")

            Next x
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```